# What is the name of the Agent to connect a Linux server to Azure Log Analytics Workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-oms

I have the need to send my logs to Azure for my custom product.  The users of my product can decide what to do (if anything) with these logs.   I created a Log Analytics Workspace in the Azure Console.  To add a Linux server, I clicked on Advanced Settings, then Connected Sources -> Linux Servers and followed the link to “Download Agent for Linux”, which took me to a Git Hub project.  The agent worked and added my server to the workspace.  What confused me is the name of the agent, “Microsoft OMS Agent for Linux GA v1.9.0-0”.  I have recently read articles that indicate the OMS Portal is retired and is moving to the Azure Portal.

First did I do this correct?

Second, is this the Linux agent that will be used going forward, or will it be renamed to remove OMS from the name?

Is this the Azure Log Analytics agent that I should use and it was previously referred to as the Microsoft Monitoring Agent (MMA) or OMS Linux agent?
Thank you if you can clear this up for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes, what you did was correct.

The answer to your second question is yes, most probably this should be the Linux agent that will be used going forward as well because as per this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/terminology#april-2018---retirement-of-operations-management-suite-brand article the changes and protential improvements with respect to single integrated platform for monitoring has been made to experience in the Azure portal but their functionality hasn't changed. Also, as per this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-linux article the OMS agents will just be referred as Log Analytics agents. The same was seen in overview part of this -> https://github.com/Microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux install guide as well.

The answer to your third question is yes, this is the Log Analytics agent you would have to use. For windows the extension / agent is referred as "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent" and for Linux it is referred as "OMSAgentForLinux".

Hope this helps!!